# How to prevent date timer have negative values? - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer, calendar

I have a date timer. When it reaches the needed value it continues to go further in the negative values. How could I prevent this?

It works in the next way: e.g. user picked 14 days. After that countdown starts - 13...12...11...0 and it doesn't stop, continues to go -1...-2...

I want my `numDaysWithToday` to stop going further if it is <=0.

Code:

```
var numDaysWithToday: Int {
///dayFromNow is 14 days for example
    get{
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to:
        dateFromNow).day!
    }
}
Text("\(numDaysWithToday) days left")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `max` function to prevent this

```swift
var numDaysWithToday: Int {
///dayFromNow is 14 days for example
    get{
        let value = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: dateFromNow).day!
        return max(value, 0)
    }
}
Text("\(numDaysWithToday) days left")
```